# Handling Multer Errors

Tags: node.js, multer, cloudinary

Please I would like to handle all errors from multer while uploading files to cloudinary and create my own custom error messages. How would I do that?

This is the cloudinary and multer configuration

```
const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
    cloudinary: cloudinary,
    params: {
        folder: "Products",
        format: async (req, file) => {
            "jpg", "png";
        }, 
        public_id: (req, file) => {
            console.log(
                new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, "-") + file.originalname
            );
            return (
                new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, "-") + file.originalname
            );
        },
    },
});

const parser = multer({ storage: storage });
```

And this is the route

```
router.post("/addProduct", middleware.IsMerchant, parser.array("Images", 3), async(req, res)=>{
    const { ProductName, Description, Category, Price} = req.body
    try {
        let product = new Product({
            ProductName,
            Description,
            Category,
            Price
        })
        if (req.files) { // if you are adding multiple files at a go
            const imageURIs = []; // array to hold the image urls
            const files = req.files; // array of images
            for (const file of files) {
                const { path } = file;
                imageURIs.push(path);
            };
            product['Images'] = imageURIs;
            product.Owner.id = req.user._id
            product.Owner.username = req.user.username
            await product.save();
            console.log("added new product")
            req.flash("success", "You did it")
            res.status(201).redirect("back"); 
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

Comment: You may refer to this [detailed documentation on integrating](https://medium.com/@joeeasy_/uploading-images-to-cloudinary-using-multer-and-expressjs-f0b9a4e14c54) Cloudinary SDK with Multer, which includes error handling where you could customize your error messages.

Comment: @epasos_573 the documentation is nice but it doesnt contain my desired answers